# Permission denied when trying to run MongoDb inside Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I try to run MongoDb, using this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo:
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: history
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
    hostname: mongodb-server
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/001_users.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001_users.js:ro
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db
```

Locallly, I have `mongo` folder and nested `mongo/data` folder, which I try to map to `/data/db` inside Docker. I also have `001_users.js` with such content:

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "test",
        pwd: "test",
        roles:[
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "history"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

However, when I run it, like:

```
$ docker-compose up mongo
```

I see error message in the console:

> mongo_1            | find: '/data/db': Permission denied

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it? PS. Since I'm using CentOS on my host machine, I tried to run `setenforce 0` before running docker-compose, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try without the `:ro` in your first volume map?

Comment: @DannyB. What is `:ro`?

Comment: Your first volume definition is `- ./mongo/001_users.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001_users.js:ro` - which is Read Only. Just remove the `:ro` part, see if it helps.